# Exclude certain files from compiling in directory

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-assembly, csc

I am trying to create multi file assembly by creating `.netmodules` for respective Visual Studio projects. These `.netmodules` are being created successfully. Command used to produce the modules:

```
csc.exe "/out:$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).netmodule" "/t:module" "/recurse:$(ProjectDir)*.cs"
```

The problem with the above command is the switch `:/recurse:$(ProjectDir)*.cs,` which compiles all files in the project including `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. This file is compiled for each project.

At the end when I am trying to build a multi file assembly using following command:

```
csc.exe /t:library /out:MultiFile.dll /addmodule:Foo.netmodule /addmodule:Boo.netmodule
```

I get the error `error CS7061: Duplicate 'GuidAttribute' attribute in 'Foo.netmodule'`

Please state any ways to create multi file assembly.

As of me, I can think of two ways, deleting the AssemblyInfo.cs files from project or find a way to exclude the specific files from compiling in the `/recurse` switch (don't know how to exclude the file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it would be nice to pass some parameter to `CSC.exe` to exclude some files from `/recurse` switch. I did not find it anywhere.
Solution I opted for:

1. Copy all source files for each Visual Studio project to different folder, excluding the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.
2. Compile all the files from that folder to produce `.netmodule.`